# Registry Key Get Value returns NULL

Tags: c#

Why does the following code return NULL for `shellValue`?

```
        string shellValue;
        RegistryKey shellKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
        shellKey = shellKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
        shellValue = shellKey.GetValue("Shell") as string;
```

I do have Administrator privileges.

Comment: Works fine for me, check whether Key/Value exist using `regedit.exe`

Comment: It does exist, default value in Windows is explorer.exe

Answer (score 3):

You are actually getting this subkey "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell".  This is because some keys are redirected by WOW64.  Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info.

Try the following:

```
string shellValue;
RegistryKey shellKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);;
shellKey = shellKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
shellValue = shellKey.GetValue("Shell") as string;
```